# How to use array of objects as NSCollectionview Datasource in Xcode MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, xcode10, nscollectionview

Hiii.

As a beginner, I have an array of imageViews with this code:

```
var imageViews = [NSImageView]()
```

and they are filled with images from a folder in my system. I want a way to use them in a collectionView as data source. Is it possible?

Comment: Only way to find out is to give it a try and see if it works

Comment: @MichaelFourre the problem is that I don't know how. I have read some tutorials but couldn't understand and none of them was short and quick.I tested it but it's not going to work like---> collectionView.dataSource = imageViews        after error, Xcode fixed the code to this---> collectionView.dataSource = imageViews as? NSCollectionViewDataSource  and its not working even for one item.

Comment: You don’t want to be using `NS*` classes in Swift. Try looking for tutorials about `UICollectionView` instead of `NSCollectionView` and see if that works better. If you still have trouble then please post about a tutorial you tried and show us your attempted implementation so that we can go from there.

Comment: @MichaelFourre this is a complete tutorial I found: [https://www.raywenderlich.com/783-nscollectionview-tutorial]. and its not that simple for a beginner like me. I have created the same app in windows and works as I want. after finding the images from their folders, i add them to an array. I just want to show items of this array in a custom or auto grid. but here its not easy like windows form where we can do it with a less than a single line of code! and isn't UI* for IOS? I want to use it for Mac. I don't know why the internet is full of ways to code for IOS but its hard to find them fo Mac